# Java List.add() method

Tags: java, list, collections

Below is the method `add()` of Java `List` `Interface`; if I loop through it 7 times adding `i` to the `0`th position like so.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    list.add(0, i);
}
```

Wouldn't it overwrite the value at that position, so I would end up with just one value of 6 in the list? Am I right, in assuming that?

Comment: Don't assume, try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you add at a position, it shifts everything starting at that position to the right.

So if you actually did this, you should end up with the following list:

```
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Read the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29

Or better yet, give it an actual try.

Answer (score 1):

according to this doc on list [List for Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E))
it pushes the element to the right of the list adding one to the indices

Comment: I actually figured that out, please see my comment above, but much appreciate your response Sir.

Comment: glad you got what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have,

```
mylist = ["Bashful","Awful","Jumpy","Happy"]
```

then,

```
mylist.add(2,"Doc")
```

makes the ArrayList

```
mylist = ["Bashful","Awful","Doc","Jumpy","Happy"]
```

Notice that the indices of "Jumpy" and "Happy" have changed from 2 to 3, and 3 to 4, accordingly.