# How does List.add(index,element) work internally in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

As mentioned in [Java API Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311369/java-list-add-method), the list.add(index,element) results in the given element being added at the given index. In the process, the subsequent list items are shifted by one position to the right (by *adding one to their indices* as mentioned in the API Doc)

My question is how does this happen practically?

Suppose we have an ArrayList containing 100 elements and we say `add(0, 6)`, now how would the API accomplish this action, given the fact that the underlying Data Structure is an array?

***More specifically: Would all the existing 100 elements be copied to its immediate right location? Or is there a more efficient way by which this is handled?***

Comment: Why not just look at the [**source code**](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l448) if you want to see how it is done? You can find it in the link I provided for you, and you can find it in the JDK you have installed. Very easy to look at that source code if you're using a good IDE. You are using an IDE, right? If not, save yourself a lot of hassle and get one now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `ArrayList` the elements will indeed be moved up. This is just linear memory access so actually surprisingly fast.

Inserting at the front is faster with an `ArrayDeque`, which uses a cyclic buffer. That is, not only does it keep track of the last element index, but also the first and the array wraps around. Unfortunately, `ArrayDeque` does not implement `List` which it arguably should do.

The very slow `LinkedList` can remove the first element quickly but is generally very slow.

The source code for all of these classes is freely available and not too complex.